# Trying to grab an Image from a Wordpress Post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Ive cobbled together the following code and it works, but it feels too hacky:

```
function get_my_img() {
if($imgs = get_posts(array(
    'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'DESC'
    ))){
foreach($imgs as $img) {
    $img_med = wp_get_attachment_image($img->ID,'medium');
    }
foreach($imgs as $img) {
    $img_larg = wp_get_attachment_image($img->ID,'large');
    }
if (preg_match('/<img.+?src(?: )*=(?: )*[\'"](.*?)[\'"]/si', $img_larg, $img_r)){
    echo '<a class="myimage" href="' . $img_r[1] .'">' . $img_med .'</a>';} 
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure there is a far simpler way to do this that I've completely overlooked.

In essence, when this function is called inside the *loop*, it outputs the last image (attached) in the current post in it's *medium* size wrapped in a link to its *large* size.

Any insight Would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much simpler to do:

```
function get_my_img() {
if($imgs = get_posts(array(
    'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'DESC'
    ))){

    $img_med = wp_get_attachment_image($imgs[0]->ID,'medium');
    $img_larg = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imgs[0]->ID,'large');

    echo '<a class="myimage" href="' . $img_larg[0] .'">' . $img_med .'</a>';
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The preg_match() stuff is not necessary. If you print $img_med and $img_larg, you'll see that they're arrays, containing three elements: The path to the image, the width and the height. So you can output the html you need with those.